# How is my loop giving me only to the second index. and not get the third index element

Tags: python, loops

My loop cannot give me the third index element.
i want to clear one more thing ,that after iteration it's not giving me the last index.

INPUT:

```
4

word

localization

internationalization

pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

output:

```
word

l10n

i18n

p43s
```

My code:

```py
n=int(input())
# print(n)
for i in range(1,n+3):
    count=0
    l=list(input())
    # print(l)
    if len(l)==0:
        pass
    elif len(l)>=10:
        start=l[0]
        end=l[-1]
        for x in l:
            print(x,end="")
    else:
        print("".join(l))
```

Comment: I don't understand what is the second or third index.

Comment: actually loop cannot give me the last element

Comment: What does the output look like when you uncomment the `print(l)` line?

Comment: if i print(l) it gives me the last index.but after iteration.it doesn't give the last index.

Comment: I think you meant to have this as your loop: `for i in range(n+3):`

Comment: I didn't understand the concept .Could you explain more ?

Comment: still not give the last index.

Comment: The `range()` class allows you to iterate over a range of values, but it stops before the 'stop' parameter. My suggestion make `range()` start one value earlier (ie `0`), so the loop will now iterate one extra time.

Comment: @AyyoubESSADEQ i want to convey that in for loop it perfectly working.but in the iteration it does not give me the last indexing.

Comment: i start range from 0 still same problem.

Comment: It works for me: With `range(1,n+3)` it stops at `internationalization`. With `range(n+3)` it stops at `pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis`

Comment: @quamrana please provide the code .if (possible) and preffer ide which you are using.because i am getting ***runtime error***

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was simulating your input. I forgot about the first blank line between `4` and `word`. So you need: `for i in range(n+4):` or rather more generally: `for i in range(2 * n):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a better way to do it :

```
f = 'localisation'
output = f[0]+str(len(f[1:len(f)-1]))+f[len(f)-1]
print(output)
```

Or to implement a function :

```
def(f):
   output = f[0]+str(len(f[1:len(f)-1]))+f[len(f)-1]
   return output
```

Comment: Your code outputs: `loca`. I think the OP wants `l10n`.

Comment: @Ayyoub ESSADEQ   Can you please explain?

Comment: @MohdAliAbbas you take the first character then you calculate the length from the second character until the one before the last character then add the last character . This what my code do .